# How do you solve 'dict' object has no attribute 'write'?

Tags: python, json, url

I haven't worked with JSON files before, and I think maybe I'm just a little lost on how to pull data in. Here's my code:

```
# Loads data on women breastfeeding in America from the web # 
import urllib.request
import json 
with urllib.request.urlopen("https://chronicdata.cdc.gov/views/8hxn-cvik/rows.json?accessType=DOWNLOAD") as web_data:
    data = json.loads(web_data.read().decode())
    json.dump(data, web_data)
```

I'm trying to pull in the data from the internet, as the link itself is a webpage view, and my computer refused to let me save it onto my computer. I want to be able to manipulate the data, but I've run into several problems. With the above code, I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnsupportedOperation                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-7f3487bc83ea> in <module>()
      6     data = json.loads(web_data.read().decode())
      7     #write_data=data.write()
----> 8     json.dump(data, web_data)

~\OneDrive\Documents\Python stuff\Pythonstuff\lib\json\__init__.py in dump(obj, fp, skipkeys, ensure_ascii, check_circular, allow_nan, cls, indent, separators, default, sort_keys, **kw)
    178     # a debuggability cost
    179     for chunk in iterable:
--> 180         fp.write(chunk)
    181 
    182 

UnsupportedOperation: write
```

I tried the following, thinking it had something to do with the .read():

```
import urllib.request
import json 
with urllib.request.urlopen("https://chronicdata.cdc.gov/views/8hxn-cvik/rows.json?accessType=DOWNLOAD") as web_data:
    data = json.loads(web_data.read().decode())
    write_data=data.write()
    json.dump(write_data, web_data)
```

And then I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-7ce187449c36> in <module>()
      5 with urllib.request.urlopen("https://chronicdata.cdc.gov/views/8hxn-cvik/rows.json?accessType=DOWNLOAD") as web_data:
      6     data = json.loads(web_data.read().decode())
----> 7     write_data=data.write()
      8     json.dump(write_data, web_data)

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'write'
```

Can someone help point me in the right direction? I'm lost as to how I can open this file and start manipulating the data. I'll eventually want to be able to manipulate some things into a data frame from there.

Comment: I don't think you should be writing to `web_data`. If you want to save something on your computer you need to open a new file with write permissions and dump the data there. Maybe I just didn't understand the problem here.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to write the data to a file and save it in your computer, right? Then you should open the file that you want to write to (I'm calling it `rows.json` here):

```py
import urllib.request
import json

with urllib.request.urlopen("https://chronicdata.cdc.gov/views/8hxn-cvik/rows.json?accessType=DOWNLOAD") as web_data:
    data = json.loads(web_data.read().decode())
    with open("rows.json", "w") as out_file:
        json.dump(data, out_file)
```